# Is it possible to convert PDF to JPG with the python module Wand and use in flight the result?

Tags: python, reportlab, wand

To insert an image.pdf in a report builded with reportlab, one way is to convert firstly the image.pdf to image.jpg by using for example Wand:

```
from wand.image import Image as wandImage
from reportlab.platypus import Image

....

with wandImage(filename='input.pdf') as img:
                img.crop(42, 64, 552, 677) # (left, top, width, height)
                img.save(filename = "output.jpg")

img = Image("output.jpg", 175.0*mm, 30.0*mm) 
img.hAlign = 'CENTER'
rapport.append(img)

...
```

It may seem inelegant to save a file.jpg and open this file just after. Is it possible to use directly the result without the save step ? For example this idiot code (that does not work !):

```
from wand.image import Image as wandImage
from reportlab.platypus import Image

....
with wandImage(filename='input.pdf') as img:
            img.crop(42, 64, 552, 677) # (left, top, width, height)
            img2 = img.convert('jpeg')
            img3 = Image(img2, 175.0*mm, 30.0*mm)  # 2508px × 430px
            img3.hAlign = 'CENTER'
            rapport.append(img3)

...
```

Comment: where the source file and the converted file locations?

Comment: @newGIS, The idea is precisely to do not convert the source file.pdf by using in flight the converted source file !!!!